# If an SVM decision boundary is the perpendicular bisector of the line connecting the support vectors, why iterate for it using a loss function?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, linear-algebra

Would it not make more sense to do some linear algebra to find the vector of the decision boundary? Is that more computationally expensive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find the support vectors!

Anyway, the title is not quite correct, because there can be many support vectors, so "the line connecting" them doesn't necessarily exist.